# MongoDB aggregation: Get samples at specific intervals

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection containing timestamped documents. The important part of their shape is:

```
{
  receivedOn: {
    date: ISODate("2018-10-01T07:50:06.836Z")
  }
}
```

They are indexed on the date.

These documents relate to and contain data from UDPs constantly arriving at a server. The rate of the UDPs vary, but there are usually around 20 per second

I'm trying to take samples from this collection. I have a list of timestamps, and I want to get the documents closest to these timestamps in the past.

For example, if I have the following documents

```
{_id: 1, "receivedOn.date": ISODate("2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")}
{_id: 2, "receivedOn.date": ISODate("2018-10-01T00:00:02.000Z")}
{_id: 3, "receivedOn.date": ISODate("2018-10-01T00:00:04.673Z")}
{_id: 4, "receivedOn.date": ISODate("2018-10-01T00:00:05.001Z")}
{_id: 5, "receivedOn.date": ISODate("2018-10-01T00:00:09.012Z")}
{_id: 6, "receivedOn.date": ISODate("2018-10-01T00:00:10.065Z")}
```

and the timestamps

```
new Date("2018-10-01T00:00:05.000Z")
new Date("2018-10-01T00:00:10.000Z")
```

I want the result to be

```
[
    {_id: 3, "receivedOn.date": ISODate("2018-10-01T00:00:04.673Z")},
    {_id: 5, "receivedOn.date": ISODate("2018-10-01T00:00:09.012Z")}
]
```

Using aggregation, I made this work. The following code gives the correct result, but it is slow and appears to have complexity `O(n*m)`, where `n` is number of matched documents and `m` is number of timestamps

```
const timestamps = [
    new Date("2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")
    new Date("2018-10-01T00:00:05.000Z")
    new Date("2018-10-01T00:00:10.000Z")
];

collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {
        $and: [
            {"receivedOn.date": {$lte: new Date("2018-10-01T00:00:10.000Z")}},
            {"receivedOn.date": {$gte: new Date("2018-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")}}
    ]},
    {$project: ...},
    {$sort: {"receivedOn.date": -1}},
    {$bucket: {
        groupBy: "$receivedOn.date",
        boundaries: timestamps,
        output: {
            docs: {$push: "$$CURRENT"}
        }
    }},
    // The buckets contain sorted arrays. The first element is the newest
    {$project: {
        doc: {
            $arrayElemAt: ["$docs", 0]
        }
    }},
    // Lift the document out of its bucket wrapper
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: "$doc"}}
]);
```

Is there a way to make this faster? Like somehow telling `$bucket` that the data is sorted? I assume what is taking most time here is `$bucket` trying to figure out which bucket to put the document in. Or is there another, better way to do this?

I've also tried running one `findOne` query per timestamp in parallel. That also gives the correct result, and is much faster, but having a few thousand timestamps is not uncommon. I don't want to do thousands of queries each time I need to do this.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/#pipeline-operators-and-indexes you can benefit from indexes only on the first stage.

Comment: I'm using it in the `$match` stage. See edit